# Use object as list index in Python

Tags: python, class, overriding

I'm wondering whether it is possible to use an object to access a particular value in a list.

For instance, take the following code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, label):
        self.label = label

    def __int__(self):
        return int(self.label)

distances = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]

node = Node("2")
print(distances[node]) # I expected this to be treated as distances[2]
```

This will give an error, as `node` is not a valid index for `distances[node]`. I was hoping that by defining `__int__` in my `Node` class that it would implicitly cast the node to an integer, which could then be treated like a valid index.

So, I'm wondering if there is a way in which I can make the following work (perhaps by overriding a method of some sort?):

```
print(distances[node])  # Desired Output: 30
```

without having to do something like the following:

```
print(distances[int(node)])
```

Comment: Just use `distances[node.id]`. Or do you mean that you want a `dict` instead of a `list`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can subclass int type and override accordingly.

```
class Node(int):
    def __init__(self, label):
        self.label = label

    def __int__(self):
        return int(self.label)


distances = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]

node = Node("2")

print(distances[node])
```

Comment: Your answer still works with new question (bad op!), but you need to retain the `int` conversion in `return int(self.id)` (which is now `self.label`).

Comment: Nice, this looks perfect! Exactly what I was after. I'll accept it as answered in a few minutes

Comment: @kabanus actually by default it will typecast first argument to int as the value of the  object. So it will work even without the type conversion. 

The definition of __int__ does not reflect the value represented by the node object.

Comment: I would revert that `int(self.label)` in the edit, and mention your comment in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should us distance[node.id] since you want to call the attribute id of the object node.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id

    def __int__(self):
        return self.id

distances = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]

node = Node(2)

In [1] : print(distances[node.id]) # I expected this to be treated as distances[2]
Out[1] : 30
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, I've modified my question a little. What if `id` is a string (`label`) instead?